# Apache POI upgrade to 5.0 error for Word document

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, apache-poi

We are upgrading Apache poi library from 3.17 to 5.0 version, when we update poi 5.2 dependency in POM.XML, getting the below mentioned error, while creating the document from template.

Code to create document

```
String relativeUrl = "/report-templates/DocTemplate.docx";
        XWPFDocument wordDoc=new XWPFDocument(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(relativeUrl));
    wordDoc.enforceUpdateFields();
```

Error Message

```
"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[] org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTFootnotesImpl.getXmlObjectArray(javax.xml.namespace.QName, org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[])'",
```

[image]

Dependency used for POI

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

We tried different ways, like adding latest dependencies of all related jars explicitly like xmlbean, poi-ooxml-schema, commons collections jars etc, but still not working.

Adding POM.xml for reference below

```
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.1</version>
            </dependency> 
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
                        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Full Stack trace:

```
    2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[] org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTFootnotesImpl.getXmlObjectArray(javax.xml.namespace.QName, org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[])'

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTFootnotesImpl.getFootnoteArray(CTFootnotesImpl.java:52)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFootnotes.onDocumentRead(XWPFFootnotes.java:85)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.initFootnotes(XWPFDocument.java:262)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:155)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:169)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:119)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//com.example.test.service.impl.testReportServiceImpl.createWordReport(testReportServiceImpl.java:890)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//com.example.test.service.impl.testReportServiceImpl.generateWordReport(testReportServiceImpl.java:821)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

2022-06-06 07:40:38 ERROR stderr:71 -   at deployment.test-web.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
```

Comment: Please show the full stack-trace. We need to see what code tries to call `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTFootnotesImpl.getXmlObjectArray`. I suspect there is a incompatibility between the used versions of Apache POI, OOXML-Schemas and/or one of the Java XML libraries.

Comment: There seems to be either an old version of `ooxml-schemas` or an old version of `xmlbeans` in your class-path on runtime. Apache Poi version 5.2.2 needs `poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2` (or `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.2`) instead of `ooxml-schemas` and it needs `xmlbeans-5.0.3`. Both provide the method `getXmlObjectArray`. But `ooxml-schemas` and `xmlbeans-3.1.0` and lower do not provide that method.

Comment: To your edit: Please check the full `dependency:tree`. There **must not** be any `ooxml-schemas` or `poi-ooxml-schemas`. And there **must not** be any `xmlbeans` of versions lower than `xmlbeans-5.0.3`. If there are such dependencies, then the libraries which pulled those are not compatible with `apache poi 5.2.2.`.